# Image technique adopted by Facebook and Google

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, facebook, image

What is the image uploading Technique adopted by facebook and google such that they show first, the faded image and then the full quality picture and also they reduced the image file size.

And when i download one of the image which i uploaded in facebook and reupload it in some another site then same effect is shown first the faded image appear and then the full quality image. How this can be done. I have a site in php and i think facebook also uses some php technique for this.

Answer (score 4):

It's called progressive compression.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#JPEG_compression

When using GD to process images in PHP you need to use `imageinterlace()` to set progressive image compression:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imageinterlace.php

But be aware that facebook uses another technique on displaying images in a way that feels faster. They first scale up the tumbnail image into the overlay image viewer and then load the hgh quality image on top of that. That way it feels as if the image begins to load instantly.